# Data table post request params not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ajax

I am new to AngularJS and DataTables. I am working on a project using an AngularJS front-end and a Rails back-end.

I am trying to use DataTables in my project using AJAX POST method but DataTable AJAX POST method is sending **data params** constants.

When I am using a normal AJAX POST request it works fine. I don't know why DataTables POST AJAX is not working.

Please help me to solve this problem.

### Using AJAX call in AngularJS

```
$.ajax({
   data: JSON.stringify({
       "key1": "value1",
       "key2": "value2"
   }),
   headers: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(){
       console.log("error");
   },
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:3000/api"
 });
```

This code AJAX POST.

It gives the correct success response.

### DataTables POST request

```
$scope.studentList = {
   bFilter: false,
   paging:   false,
   bRetrieve : true,
   ajax: {
       data: JSON.stringify({
       "key1": "value1",
       "key2": "value2"
   }),
   headers: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(){
       console.log("error");
   },
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:3000/api"
   processData: false,
 },
 columns: [
     {}]
};
```

It throws the following error on the server-side. Is there any mistake in my code?

#### Error occurred while parsing request parameters.

Contents:

> 0=%7B&1=%22&2=s&3=t&4=a&5=n&6=d&7=a&8=r&9=d&10=*&11=i&12=d&13=%22&14=%3A&15=4&16=0&17=%2C&18=%22&19=s&20=e&21=c&22=t&23=i&24=o&25=n&26=*&27=i&28=d&29=%22&30=%3A&31=8&32=%2C&33=%22&34=y&35=e&36=a&37=r&38=%22&39=%3A&40=2&41=0&42=1&43=6&44=%2C&45=%22&46=m&47=o&48=n&49=t&50=h&51=%22&52=%3A&53=2&54=%2C&55=%22&56=d&57=a&58=t&59=e&60=%22&61=%3A&62=1&63=8&64=%7D

Even though I am using **processData: false** option it still throws the following error on the server-side.

#### Error occurred while parsing request parameters.

Contents:

> [object Object]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Check out this: https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/26282/posting-json-with-built-in-ajax-functionality

Answer (score 1):

In dataTables you can not pass a string in data, you need a function:

```
var dataObject = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
};

var table = $('#exampleTable').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    "url": "urlExample.com",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": function(d) {
      $.extend(d, dataObject);
      return JSON.stringify(d);
    },
    "dateType": "json",
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  }
});
```

Comment: This thing that I need a function is weird but worked for me as well, I spent hours digging and checking with debugger in a new csharp service working fine from direct ajax call but failing with Datatable and magically adding a function solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing JSON.stringify. data table or ajax internally handles JSON parsing/stringification.

Comment: Where did you dig this question out? :) - posted `11 months ago` :)

Comment: does my answer help you?

Comment: I have just seen the question in the `active` queue. I haven't had this issue myself personally.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data.json",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": function (d) {
            return JSON.stringify(d);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
// "processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
  "ajax": 'controller/documents/getDocExpAjax',
  "type": 'POST',
  "data": function (d) {
     return JSON.stringify(d);
  },
  "dateType": "json",
  "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```